# How I can convert TDlib to Telethon sessions

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, pyrogram, tdlib

I use software to administer my channels. Which requires a lot of teleton session. Recently I have encountered the problem that teleton sessions are rapidly burning out after registration. I read that tdlib sessions are much more durable. My question is how can I automate the creation of sessions using tdlib? And how can I convert them to teleton sessions. I would really appreciate your help!
I tried a bunch of options, including creating sessions on phones via appium with re-registration via telethon. Sessions still expire after a day, mostly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.